# Save edited information in an AspxGridView

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using a DevExpress AspxGridView that has columns with checkboxes. I managed to make the checkboxes editable, however I can't find a way to retrieve the controls in the grid. I found that the grid has methods like GetRow and GetRowValues but they retrieve information from the datasource which isn't useful to me.

If you're wondering why I'm not using the built-in editing method with Edit buttons on each row, it's because I want the user to instantly edit the checkboxes and I want all the changes to be saved after clicking a button outside the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've added a checkBox to the column's DataItemTemplate container.  If so, to obtain an editor instance, use the ASPxGridView's [FindRowCellTemplateControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindRowCellTemplateControltopic) method.  An example of the requested functionality can be found at:

[to get/set values in checkbox of aspxgridview](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q97037)